# Can I run WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 with Java 7

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-esb

When you set JAVA_HOME to point at a Java 7 JDK, WSO2 ESB doesn't start - obviously this is due to the block in wso2server.sh entitled 'Handle the SSL issue with proper JDK version.'

I can comment this out, and the server will start; but what is the 'the SSL Issue'? I have searched various forums but have found no answer regarding this. It looks like Carbon works with JDK6 and higher; is this the case?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It works with Java 7.

The start up script is just not smart enough to look for JDK 1.6 AND HIGHER. It's only detecting for 1.6. So you can comment out the version check if you know you are only going to use 7 or higher.

```
jdk_16=`$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version 2>&1 | grep 1.6`

if [ "$jdk_16" = "" ]; then
   echo " [ERROR] CARBON is supported only on JDK 1.6 and higher"
   exit 1
fi
```

If running on 1.5 or earlier is a possibility, it might be easier to detect for these earlier version than for 1.6 or later.

Answer (score 0):

It worked if you followup above post, but we are not encouraging to use this in long run, since it has been never tested, and also recently we have found there is a bug in JDK 7 when runs in high concurrency but it says the given issue has been fixed with the JDK 7 latest version, so you better check you version of testing.